# Manhwa where the number one ranked player lost to the number two player, and then deleted his account

Tags: story-identification, manga

It is about a game where the MC is the player who is ranked 1 in that particular game(at least from what I remember)and was a blacksmith. He lost to the 2nd ranked player who I think was a woman mage. After he lost he deleted his account and the mage became the 1st ranked player in the game. I think he was lucky too and maybe later returned to the game.

Can someone please tell me the name of this manhwa? It was from CarroToon, I think. I can say more but I don't want to make it too long but that's what I remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you recall more details about the story, please include them in your question. Don't worry about making the question too long, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is ***[I'm Destined for Greatness!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=157519)***.

> When you succeed at everything you try, you have no choice but to seek challenges elsewhere, like in a game. By using the trash jobs that no one pays any attention to, with the right attitude you're bound to accomplish your goals! even succeeding at the most impossible of quests, the main character bets everything he has. "With my skills, I'll beat this game!"

As you said, the MC has the job class 'blacksmith', and he fights and loses to a female mage (a necromancer) in the first chapter. She offers him a rematch, as she felt she was lucky to win, but rather than accept it, he instead quits the game.

[image]

Comment: @Idontremembermanhuas - If anyone correctly identifies the story you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.